# Confusion setting Worker Role diagnostics with Powershell

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-diagnostics

I want to ensure that my Worker Role always has the correct Diagnostics configured, but I am having a couple of issues and finding the documentation on this *very* unclear.

I had the diagnostics set up on the Worker Role and functioning as expected; for example the WAD tables were all being populated.

This has been working for many months and we have deployed (via the Swap VIP from Staging to Production) new versions of the Worker Role and the diagnostics have continued to function as expected.

Recently, however, we deployed a new version of the Worker Role (again, via the Swap VIP) and the diagnostics have been removed.  Using the

```
Get-AzureServiceDiagnosticsExtension -ServiceName "blah" -Slot "Production"
```

cmdlet I can see that, indeed there is no diagnostics config on the Worker Role.

Clearly I am missing something with how I configure the Worker Role using the

```
Set-AzureServiceDiagnosticsExtension
```

**[The documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn495270.aspx) is very unclear about what the `-Role` and `-Slot` parameters do**

(empahsis mine)

> -Role<String[]>
>
> An optional array of roles to specify the diagnostics configuration for. If not specified the diagnostics configuration **is applied as the default configuration** for all roles.

*Does this mean that immediately all deployments get the config, no matter their Role or Slot?  Or does it mean that I am setting the "default" for any deployments that I make afterwards?  If I have latterly run this command with the -Slot parameter, will this affect the "default"? Why does the `Get-AzureServiceDiagnosticExtension **not** have a -Role param?*

> -Slot<String>
>
> Specifies the environment of the deployment to modify. Supported values are "Production" or "Staging".

*But what if I don't provide -Slot?  Does this mean that all slots **immediately** get the config? How does -Slot work with -Role as there is no mention of "default" here like the -Role documentation?*

Additional confusion comes from the fact that `Remove-AzureServiceDiagnosticsExtension` **also has -Slot and -Role** but the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt589183.aspx) is not clear how this tallies up with "default" configs that it describes in the `Set-` cmdlet documentation.  *Does removing without -Role or -Slot remove everything, or just the "default" that you `Set-` without -Role or -Slot?*

What I would like to do is make sure that I only have to set the Diagnostics **Once**. i.e. at the point that I first *Create* the Worker Role, I set the Diagnostics and never have to touch it again.

However, I have the added complication that I would prefer to **not** have diagnostics recorded for the *Staging*, just the *Production*.

I've been playing with the cmdlets and testing but I have no confidence because

1. The fact that diagnostics were removed on swapping a new version in even though they had been fine with previous swaps and
2. The documentation is very unclear.

**UPDATE**

To try and understand this more I have made an assumption that by `Set-`ing the Diagnostics *on the Production Slot I will get the setup that I require.

I've done this with:

```
Set-AzureServiceDiagnosticsExtension -ServiceName "MyCloudService" `
  -Slot Production -DiagnosticsConfigurationPath "<path to file>" `
  -StorageContext "<context>" -CertificateThumbprint "CERTHUMBPRINT"
```

But what you get back from `Get-` and `Remove-` are not what you would expect:

1. Get, with **no slot**

`Get-AzureServiceDiagnosticsExtension -ServiceName "MyCloudService"`

Returns an object, with ID (**NOT EXPECTED**)

> Default-PaaSDiagnostics-Production-Ext-0

2. Get, with **Production** Slot

`Get-AzureServiceDiagnosticsExtension -ServiceName "MyCloudService" -Slot Production`

Returns an object, with ID (expected)

> Default-PaaSDiagnostics-Production-Ext-0

3. Get, with **Staging** Slot

`Get-AzureServiceDiagnosticsExtension -ServiceName "MyCloudService" -Slot Staging`

Returns no object (expected)

4. Remove, with no Role or Slot

`Remove-AzureServiceDiagnosticsExtension -ServiceName "MyCloudService"`

Returns nothing to remove (expected)

> WARNING: No existing Microsoft.Azure.Diagnostics.PaaSDiagnostics extensions enabled on given roles.

5. Remove, with no Role but **Staging** Slot

`Remove-AzureServiceDiagnosticsExtension -ServiceName "MyCloudService" -Slot Staging`

Returns nothing to remove (expected)

> WARNING: No existing Microsoft.Azure.Diagnostics.PaaSDiagnostics extensions enabled on given roles.

6. Remove, with Role "MyRole" and **Staging** Slot

`Remove-AzureServiceDiagnosticsExtension -ServiceName "MyCloudService" -Role "MyRole" -Slot Staging`

Returns nothing to remove (expected)

> WARNING: No existing Microsoft.Azure.Diagnostics.PaaSDiagnostics extensions enabled on given roles.

7. Remove, with no Role but **Production** Slot

`Remove-AzureServiceDiagnosticsExtension -ServiceName "MyCloudService" -Slot Production`

Returns nothing to remove (**NOT EXPECTED**)

> WARNING: No existing Microsoft.Azure.Diagnostics.PaaSDiagnostics extensions enabled on given roles.

8. Remove, with Role "MyRole" and **Production** Slot

`Remove-AzureServiceDiagnosticsExtension -ServiceName "MyCloudService" -Role "MyRole" -Slot Staging`

Return successful remove (**NOT EXPECTED**)

> WARNING: Removing PaaSDiagnostics configuration for MyRole from Cloud Service MyCloudService.

I don't understand why a `Get-` with **no Slot** would return the Diagnostics, but a `Remove-` with **no Role or Slot** says there is nothing there.

Equally, why does the `Remove-` not work **without the Role** rather than **with the Role**?

Comment: It does seem the document is unclear for `-role` and `-slot`, I would assume the same as you. If you always deploy straight to `production` slot, you should be able to set it and forget it. However, Worker Role diagnostics extension stays with the deployment slot. If there is a swap while the extension is in place, it's status will become fubar, and result of `get-` and `set-` will become funny too. When I know where the extension exactly is, `Remove-AzureServiceDiagnosticsExtension -ServiceName $serviceName -Role $role -Slot $slot` seems to be working as expected to me.